# In Swift, how can you use NSPredicate to search in a custom class that contains both a string and a NSNumber?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, nspredicate, uisearchcontroller

Currently I have a search bar that searches JSON data by name:

```
  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredSearchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: " SELF CONTAINS [c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.channelArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredSearchResults = array as! [ChannelInfo]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

The filtered search results should return a custom class that contains the name searched for:

```
class ChannelInfo {

  var logo: String
  var channelName: String
  var id: NSNumber 

  init(logo: String, channelName: String , id: NSNumber) {

    self.logo = logo
    self.channelName = channelName
    self.id = id
  }
}
```

currently I'm getting an error whenever I use the search bar:

```
Can't use in/contains operator with collection .ChannelInfo (not a collection)'
```

I'm assuming it's because the custom class contains both a string and NSNumber. Any info to fix this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"channelName CONTAINS [c] %@"`

Comment: I tried that, I get the error: ChannelInfo' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[.ChannelInfo valueForKey:]

Comment: See my answer for that particular detail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to search in a custom object that doesn't support `contains` operator. You have to search in the specific fields, e.g.

```
"channelName CONTAINS [c] %@"
```

Also you will have to make `ChannelInfo` extend `NSObject` or declare it with `@objc`. `NSPredicate` uses Obj-C reflection to access field values dynamically.

Comment: I tried that, I get the error: ChannelInfo' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector -[.ChannelInfo valueForKey:]

Comment: This is my first time using NSPredicate, how would I make ChannelInfo extend NSObject or declare it with @objc?